# Why is there apparently a consensus on the P = NP question?

Tags: soft-question, computational-complexity, open-problem

So through my years of education I have heard a lot about the famous $\mathrm{P}=\mathrm{NP}$ problem. I have seen that [a significant number of mathematicians believe that this result is false](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/papers/poll.pdf) (and that $\mathrm{P} \neq \mathrm{NP}$). Of course I respect their opinion and understand they don't express anything more than their beliefs. However, the fact that the majority is so overwhelming has always stricken me.

From what I have seen from websites, talks, etc., the main argument in favor of $\mathrm{P} \neq \mathrm{NP}$ is that given our actual knowledge of mathematics, if $\mathrm{P}$ was indeed equal to $\mathrm{NP}$, we would already have a proof. In my humble opinion, this is extremely weak since breakthroughs in the world of algorithms seem to happen regularly, and that century-old problem only get solutions today thanks to new ways of seeing things (Fermat and Poincaré's conjectures are nice examples of this).

I have seen people think that $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP} \cap \mathrm{co}\text{-}\mathrm{NP}$ based on the fact that lots of problems that are in both $\mathrm{NP}$ and $\mathrm{co}\text{-}\mathrm{NP}$ are found to be in $\mathrm{P}$. Apparently the fact that $\mathrm{PRIMES}$ is in $\mathrm{P}$ wasn't that much of a surprise (even if the result is stunning) because $\mathrm{PRIMES}$ was known to be in $\mathrm{NP} \cap \mathrm{co}\text{-}\mathrm{NP}$. Same goes with linear programming.

But on the other hand, it has been shown that if $\mathrm{P} \neq \mathrm{NP}$ there are problems that belong to $\mathrm{NP}$ but are neither $\mathrm{P}$ nor $\mathrm{NP}$-complete, and we know very few problems (AFAIK) that are in this case. Furthermore, some problems in there might fall one day into one $\mathrm{P}$ (maybe Discrete Logarithm after the discovery of a [$O(n^{log (n)})$ algorithm](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.4244.pdf)?).

So I'm surely missing arguments or extrapolating too much from the little I know. Hence the question : Why is there apparently a consensus on the $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$ question?

I don't ask for everyone to state their opinion, I simply wonder about a thought process that seems to be quasi universal in the mind of numerous mathematicians. I honestly don't think this question is opinion-based.

Comment: It seems like lack of evidence is used here to suggest evidence of the lack. Remember, we are not talking "belief" here, in the religious sense. Only that there is really no evidence, not even a hint, that $NP=P$.

Comment: There's a nice post by Scott Aaronson on his blog: ["The Scientific Case for $P\neq NP$"](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=1720)

Comment: Anyone who has spent any time writing an algorithm to efficiently solve an NP complete problem will have a hard time with the concept of $P = NP$.

Comment: If P = NP then it's very hard to explain why, throughout the careers of a huge number of programmers and computer scientists, no one has ever found a polynomial-time solution to an NP-complete problem but numerous other problems readily yield polynomial-time solutions.

Comment: "the main argument in favor of P≠NP is that ... if P  was indeed equal to NP
 we would already have a proof" -- I've never seen anyone offer that as the main argument. Rather, if P = NP then a huge number of astounding and consequential things would have to be true. But that doesn't make for a proof--you have the implication arrow backwards.  The most likely reason that we don't have a proof that P = NP is that P ≠ NP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The post [Reasons to believe](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=122) from Scott Aaronson's blog states...

> *...ten arguments for believing P!=NP: arguments that are pretty much obvious to those who have thought seriously about the question, but that (with few exceptions) seem never to be laid out explicitly for those who haven’t. You’re welcome to believe P=NP if you choose. My job is to make you understand the conceptual price you have to pay for that belief.*

Together with the post from the same blog [The Scientific Case for P≠NP](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=1720) (already mentioned in a comment by user @Semiclassical), these pretty much cover the subject.

Comment: This blog has indeed some nice and clear posts. I will read them in depth for sure ! I asked the question because I wanted to know the exact reasons that real mathematicians/computer theorists developped because even if I do believe that $P \neq NP$, my Master-student reasoning might have been completely off ! Thanks for the answer, would love to see others (that maybe qualify the arguments developped here ?) !

Comment: The guy is a "real mathematician/computer theorist", whatever "real" means.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to denigrate the blog author, I was just commentating on the quotation you provided. Nice answer !

Comment: "I wanted to know the exact reasons that real mathematicians/computer theorists ..." -- Aaronson is a renowned one of those, not merely a "blog author".

Answer (score 1):

Through out the research in the latest years many people have introduced new classes of problems, in other words they tried to categorized problems considering many aspects of computation. Not only the running time as in $\mathrm{P}$ vs $\mathrm{NP}$. Or other models of calculation such as Randomized Turing Machines or even Quantum.

One particular class of interest is the polynomial hierarchy $\mathrm{PH}$ that contains many problems. Another one is $\mathrm{P/poly}$ that contains problems solved by circuits. It is proven, that if $\mathrm{P=NP}$ then many weird results are also true about these classes.

If $\mathrm{P=NP}$ many classes collapse and many problems, outside $\mathrm{NP}$ or $\mathrm{P}$  that are supposed difficult are much easier than considered now. Of course there are no results directly proving these things because it would mean $\mathrm{P=NP}$. These theorems are in the fashion of "If $\mathrm{P=NP}$  implies many counter-intuitive results that are not considered true".

That is also why most people researching this question believe them to be different. If they are equal our whole complexity world would collapse.

[The wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) is very informative. 
[Also this.](http://nanoexplanations.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/life-in-algorithmica/)